# GPU not working correctly after suspend (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, suspend

So I am using my GPU (Nvidia GeForce GTX 850M) for scientific calculations.

After a while I realized that my calculations are far too slow.

I investigated and found a huge performance drop after suspending Ubuntu.

Here is an example with ***glxgears*** Benchmark:

1. Startup Ubuntu
2. run glxgears with result ~**15000** FPS
3. cancel glxgears and suspend
4. login
5. run glxgears with result ~**200** FPS

This is consistent with my scientific calculations, where performence drops to ~1/30th after suspend. (The drop is smaller because not all calculations are done on GPU)

I tested this with and nvidia-361 and nvidia-370 drivers and can't
figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Found the following bug report about the same problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1559576

So it is an unsolved bug...

Will update if I find anything in case someone 
has the same problem.